# MongoDB trigger reference updates

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I have the following sample user collection in mongodb:

```
{
    _id: '1234',
    name: 'abc',
    age: '20',
    ...
}
```

Also orders collection with sample data as:

```
{
     _id: '6789',
     total: '300',
     cutomer: {
          _id: '1234',
          name: 'abc'
     },
     ...
}
```

On my user page, user updates his name. How do I trigger automatic update to all the user references used in orders collection.

Answer (score 1):

With something like this, you have to query for that user id and then update all records with the option `multi: true`:

```
orders.update({customer: {_id: 1234}}, {$set: {customer: {name: 'newname'}}}, {multi: true}, function (err, affectedRows) {
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: Its not working for me. I am getting `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

Comment: Please edit your question with your full code (not here).

Comment: These are the queries I executed

`db.customer.insert({ _id: '1234', name: 'abc', age: 21 })`

`db.orders.insert({ _id: '6789', "total" : "300", "customer" : { "_id" : "1234", "name" : "abc" }})`

`db.Collection.update({customer: {"_id" : '1234'}},  {$set: {cutomer: {name: 'newname'}}}, {multi: true})`

Comment: the name `Collection`was only an example you have to use your collection name `db.orders.update`, then take attention you wrote `cutomer` and `customer` those are different.